# Recovering Avro record in Pig UDF

Tags: apache-pig, avro

I have data stored using Avro, which I need to pass to a Pig UDF. What is the proper way to;

- call Pig's `FOREACH` operator to pass a whole record to the UDF, and
- "cast" the tuple into an Avro record in the UDF.

Ideally, if I have records of the type MyRecord stored in the .avro file, each with the fields A, B and C. I want to pass the entire record to the UDF (extending `EvalFunc`). In the UDF, I would then want to cast the tuple to a record of type `MyRecord` (from the compiled Avro schema). This way, I can flexibly use `MyRecord.getA()`, `MyRecord.getB()` and `MyRecord.getC()` and flexibly operate on all three fields.